# How can I put a random component in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

So, I am trying to put a random component when the user refresh the page web. How can I do it? I created my components and tried to use it like an array but it shows the index of the array when i refresh the page. For example only show 0, 1 or 2 because I have 3 items in my DATA array. Could you help me please? Thank you so much!!!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Enterprice from './components/pages/Enterprice';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Developers from './components/pages/Developers';
import Community from './components/pages/Community';
import Download from './components/pages/Download';
import SignUp from './components/pages/SignUp';
import Marketing from './components/pages/Marketing';
import Consulting from './components/pages/Consulting';
import Navbar from './components/navbar/Navbar';
import { MainFrontOne } from './components/ui/mainFront/mainFrontOne/MainFrontOne';
import { MainFrontTwo } from './components/ui/mainFront/mainFrontTwo/MainFrontTwo';
import { MainFrontThree } from './components/ui/mainFront/mainFrontThree/MainFrontThree';

function App() {

    const data =[
        <MainFrontOne/>, <MainFrontTwo/>, <MainFrontThree/>
    ]

    const [mainFrontRandom, setMainFrontRandom] = useState(null);

    const compDisplay = ()=>{
        const randomDisplay = Math.floor(Math.random()*data.length);
        setMainFrontRandom(randomDisplay)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      compDisplay()
    }, [])
    

    return (

        <>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Navbar />
                {/* <MainFrontOne/>  */}
                {/* <MainFrontTwo/>  */}
                {/* <MainFrontThree/>  */}
                {
                    mainFrontRandom
                }
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Enterprice />}/>
                    <Route path="enterprice" element={<Enterprice />}/>
                    <Route path="developers" element={<Developers />}/>
                    <Route path="community" element={<Community />}/>
                    <Route path="download" element={<Download />}/>
                    <Route path="sign-up" element={<SignUp />}/>
                    <Route path="marketing" element={<Marketing />}/>
                    <Route path="consulting" element={<Consulting />}/>
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </>

    );
}

export default App;
```

This is my third component and the others are similar.

```
import React from 'react';
import './mainFrontThree.css';

export const MainFrontThree = () => {
    return (
        <div >
            <section className="main-front-section">
                Hello world
            </section>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You are setting a random number inside mainFrontRandom and not the component. Try this: 
 setMainFrontRandom(data[randomDisplay])

Comment: Thank u for your answer, so, i tried it and in the console.log i can see the component, but it doesnt display in the in the web page when a refresh it. Now what could be it the problem??

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to fix this problem.

**1. Set the mainFrontRandom to random component**

```js
const compDisplay = () => {
        const randomDisplay = Math.floor(Math.random()*data.length);
        setMainFrontRandom(randomDisplay)
    }
```

)
}

**2. Render the component from data and use index of mainFrontRandom**

```js
    <>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Navbar />
            {/* <MainFrontOne/>  */}
            {/* <MainFrontTwo/>  */}
            {/* <MainFrontThree/>  */}
            {
                data[mainFrontRandom] <--- this changed
            }
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Enterprice />}/>
                <Route path="enterprice" element={<Enterprice />}/>
                <Route path="developers" element={<Developers />}/>
                <Route path="community" element={<Community />}/>
                <Route path="download" element={<Download />}/>
                <Route path="sign-up" element={<SignUp />}/>
                <Route path="marketing" element={<Marketing />}/>
                <Route path="consulting" element={<Consulting />}/>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </>
```

)
}

Answer (score 0):

This example works fort me even when you reload. Look at the state, the component is there and not the number. Make sure you store the component in the state and not the index. Probably that is the issue with previous example.

```
import './App.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import MainFrontOne from './MainFrontOne';
import MainFrontTwo from './MainFrontTwo';
import MainFrontThree from './MainFrontThree';

function App() {
   const data =[
        <MainFrontOne/>, <MainFrontTwo/>, <MainFrontThree/>
    ]

    const [mainFrontRandom, setMainFrontRandom] = useState(null);

    const compDisplay = ()=>{
        const randomDisplay = Math.floor(Math.random()*data.length);
        setMainFrontRandom(data[randomDisplay])
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      compDisplay()
    }, [])
    
  return (
    <div className="App">
      mainFrontRandom: {mainFrontRandom}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```